# Unable to start Neo4j Server

Tags: neo4j

The neo4j server closed due to unexpected system shut down and now I am unable to restart the server. How can I restart it without losing the data.(I can't afford to lose the data)

Here is the error log.

```
ERROR o.n.s.advanced.AdvancedBootstrapper - Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: Startup failed due to preflight task [class org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformUpgradeIfNecessary]: Unable to upgrade database
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:225) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:103) [neo4j-server-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:57) [neo4j-server-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
Caused by: org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreflightFailedException: Startup failed due to preflight task [class org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformUpgradeIfNecessary]: Unable to upgrade database
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:344) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:160) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your data store files? Have you tried changing the configuration to allow store level upgrades? (Make sure you backup your store files first)

Comment: Reducing the wrapper.java.initmemory solved the problem..seems like other processes were eating up the ram. thanks.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original poster claims that issue was resolved by decreasing the Java heap size intiial memory configuration.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-performance.html

Configure `wrapper.java.initmemory` to a value in MB that does not exceed available system memory.